# Bar Plot Comparing Two Samples R Studios

Tags: r

I am a sophmore in college and I just started learning R/Rstudios and im struggling to make a barplot that compares data between two samples.

This is what I tried but I don't know how to compare the I and U samples or how to label the X-axis for the bar plot so it is under each bar. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sample<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
I<-c(1.76,1.45,1.03,1.53,2.34,1.96,1.79,1.21)
U<-c(0.49,0.85,1.00,1.54,1.01,0.75,2.11,0.92)
cbind(sample,I,U)

     sample    I    U
[1,]      1 1.76 0.49
[2,]      2 1.45 0.85
[3,]      3 1.03 1.00
[4,]      4 1.53 1.54
[5,]      5 2.34 1.01
[6,]      6 1.96 0.75
[7,]      7 1.79 2.11
[8,]      8 1.21 0.92

barplot(I,U, ylab="weight (g)", main="Pod Weight from Inoculated(I) and Uninoculated(U) Plants")
```

Comment: First go to the basics. What is a bar plot? Can it be used to plot continuous variables? perharps you need a boxplot for each variable u and I `boxplot(data.frame(U,I))`

Answer (score 1):

To create a barplot, you would want to use `rbind` here, along with `beside = TRUE` and `names.arg`. You should also add a legend.

Though, as mentioned in the comments, take note that a barplot may not be the best way to examine your data if you are looking to compare an outcome like this between groups.

At any rate, to answer the specific coding question:

```
barplot(rbind(I,U),
        beside = TRUE,
        names.arg = sample,
        xlab = "Sample Number",
        ylab = "weight (g)", 
        main = "Pod Weight from Inoculated(I) and Uninoculated(U) Plants",
        legend.text = c("Innoculated", "Uninoculated"), 
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty = "n"))= c("grey25", "lightgrey"), bty = "n")
```

[image]

Note you mention barplot in the title, but box plot in the text, then your sample code is barplot - hence above. But as mentioned by @Onyambu you may want to consider a boxplot:

```
boxplot(data.frame(U,I), col = c("red", "darkgrey"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for noticing that I was doing a box plot for a different set of data so that was a typo 